# Red 5 media server version 1.0 finding correct Java version

Tags: java, red5

I have installed Red 5 media server version 1.0 rc2 to a windows 2008 server, 64 bit.

I am trying to start the Red 5 service, that fails and the log is as below:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.3.6
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2009 Tanuki Software, Ltd.  All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 | WrapperManager: Initializing...

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/13 15:19:16 | WrapperSimpleApp: Class
org.red5.server.Bootstrap found but could not be initialized:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/red5/server/Bootstrap :
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:18 | JVM exited while loading the application.
...
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:45 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:45 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/13 15:19:45 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

This seems from googling something to do with java version so I uninstalled the currect JDK and reinstalled  JDK 6 Update 18 as described here: http://red5guide.com/install_jdk_jre_for_red5.html

I have set the windows PATH environment variable to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin

When i run java -version I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

However I still can't start the Red 5 service with the same log given as shown above.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: The tanuki wrapper does not allow "free" use in a 64 bit environment; their paid version does. If you stick with 32 bit java you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` indicates that the compiled version should be using JDK version 7. Install that version and run it again.

Comment: thank you - this worked  it seems to want JDK 7 now for this version of RED 5. I also set the environment variables extend 'PATH' to the jdk bin folder, JAVA_HOME to jdk root folder, JAVA_VERSION to 1.7

Comment: More info: https://code.google.com/p/red5/wiki/ServerWontStart#Wrong_Java_Version